# Backbone Marionette, How to load JS file when the routes be called?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

This is my route,

```
define [
    'apps/home/index/index'
    'apps/home/edit/index'
    'apps/home/about/aboutUs'
    'apps/home/about/jobs'
],
(HomeIndex, EditIndex, aboutUsIndex, jobsIndex) ->
    class Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
        routes :
            '' : 'indexPage'
            'index' : 'indexPage'
            'edit' : 'editApp'
            'aboutUs' : 'aboutUsPage'
            'jobs' : 'jobsPage'

        indexApp : () ->
            @homeIndex = new HomeIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex

        editApp : () ->
            @homeIndex = new EditIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex

        aboutUsPage : () ->
            @homeIndex = new aboutUsIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex

        jobsPage : () ->
            @homeIndex = new jobsIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex
```

But when the route load (when it opens index only), it will load all the file that doesn't have to load now.

So, I want to change to like this, so that reduce loading time.

```
define [
    'apps/home/index/index'
],
(HomeIndex) ->
    class Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
        routes :
            '' : 'indexPage'
            'index' : 'indexPage'
            'edit' : 'editApp'
            'aboutUs' : 'aboutUsPage'
            'jobs' : 'jobsPage'

        indexApp : () ->
            @homeIndex = new HomeIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex

        editApp : () ->
            # LOAD 'apps/home/edit/index' file, if it has not loaded
            @homeIndex = new EditIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex

        aboutUsPage : () ->
            # LOAD 'apps/home/about/aboutUs' file, if it has not loaded
            @homeIndex = new aboutUsIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex

        jobsPage : () ->
            # LOAD 'apps/home/about/jobs' file, if it has not loaded
            @homeIndex = new jobsIndex()
            App.contentArea.show @homeIndex
```

Is this possible? If so, how should I do to make, please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes This is Possible You can do this using Require.js,All you need to do is just use this library in your project and make your app structure like one he demand...